# A+B using C++ language

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, tips, c++

I'm golfing a program to sum two numbers in C++.

Example:

```
10 3
13
```

I found out that this problem can be solved in 54 symbols (without spaces and so on) using C++.
My code (63 symbols):

```
#include <iostream>
main() {
    int a, b;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a + b;
}
```

I have no idea how to make my program shorter. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Do the numbers have to come from STDIN?

Comment: DJMcMayhem, yes.

Comment: I don't think you can beat that if you have to use STDIN.

Comment: I saw the 54-symbols result on site, where you can read data only from STDIN or file.

Comment: Could you link to where you saw a 54 byte solution? If you have seen a 54 byte solution why can't you use that?

Comment: I haven't seen the solution code. I saw only statistics like run time, used memory and length (54 symbols without spaces and etc.)

Comment: Your program can not  run according to c++ standard. the function `main` should have a return type.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming puzzle or code golf challenge. It's not a general programming question either, though.

Comment: @rahnema1 yes, `main` function have to be declared with a return type. Some compilers support `main() { ... }` declaration. I used that in order to make my code shorter.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline why do you think that's not a challenge? A goal is to write working A+B program, that will be shorter than mine.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline This is a perfectly fine [tag:tips] question, no reason to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 48 bytes

How about...

```
#include<cstdlib>
main(){system("tr \\  +|bc");}
```

...not using C++?

---

- The call to `system` runs commands on your shell (`<cstdlib>` declares `system`).
- `tr \\  +` executes the command [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr), translating spaces to `+` (so the input`34 45` becomes `34+45`).
- `|` [pipes](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) `tr`'s STDOUT into [`bc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)'s STDIN.
- `bc` performs equations in STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT.

Comment: Can you explain how does it work? I tried to run that program on Linux, but the next error ocured: `bc: not found`

Comment: @eaglemango Well, you have to install bc.

Comment: Mind if I edit in an explanation and some links?

Comment: @MDXF Fine. (15 chars)